# Alljoyn android sdk force crash

Tags: android, p2p

I am new to alljoyn and I just saw the alljoyn intro webinar video. I have installed the alljoyn sdk and imported the chat sample. I added the bundles jar and the daemon file to the libs folder. I also added the service to the manifest file and the one line of code to the AlljoynService class. I initially had a compile error due to startForeground because of the Api level. I then added @TargetApi(5) above the onCreate method to solve that problem. When I tried to run the app on my phone, it crashed. I also tried creating a new project and deleted all the files in it and replaced them with the files in the chat example, but I still have the same error. How do I solve this ?

Comment: can we see the stacktrace and some code?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and found this on a site

> To solve this problem, when i imported the project, i clicked the
>   "copy project into workspace" button; i then clicked on the project
>   settings and adjusted the "Order and Export" settings: i noticed the
>   alljoyn.jar and the Android2.2 boxes were not checked; so i checked
>   them. I also moved alljoyn.jar to the top of the export order (though
>   not sure that matters).

And what I did is, right click on project, then click properties, then click 'Java build and path', and check Android Private libraries; that's it.